# Pull out dynamic object name

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

There is an object which always has a different name.

Example: `{0.8337090382971908: "DELETED"}`

how can i get his name and status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) respectively along with [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring):

```js
const obj = {0.8337090382971908: "DELETED"};

const [ name ] = Object.keys(obj);
const [ status ] = Object.values(obj);

console.log(name);
console.log(status);
```